# Why my responsive theme is breaking?

Tags: magento2, theme, luma-theme, iphone

I have Magento 2 default Luma theme installed.

I noticed the home page doesn't look well on some mobile devices, especially on new iPhones. The user has to scroll right and left to see the rest of the page.

Has anyone solved this issue?
Any tips really appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug using Chrome Debug to find the divs that are larger than the screen and add the property to your CSS to the respective class `max-width:100%; with:auto;`, so apply in your images too.

Seems like your banner needs of that change.